# Which Android handsets support in-line call recording?

Tags: calls, call-recording

In-line call recording feature is not something that can be found in the specifications listed by the manufactures or on the websites aggregating such data such as GSM Arena. It is also a source of bad rep given to the developers of call recording apps because the general public does not understand that they own devices which do not support such feature for one reason or another and the app they use have nothing to do with it. A short trip around the Web only confirms that there is a lot of confusion surrounding this subject.

If you own an Android device and are able to verify whether it and its stock  ROM support in-line call recording please post the make and model. I'm not sure if the country of purchase is necessary but I would not be surprised if handsets sold in some countries had this feature enabled while in others disabled (in the same fashion as DVD players supported different regions depending on where they were sold).

The in-line recording should result in a recording where both the caller and the callee can be heard loud, clear and background noise free, just as they can hear each other during the conversation. It should be achievable while having the handset by the ear with the loudspeaker set to off.

Some information on handsets that do not have such feature can be found on the Google Play storefronts. I was initially going to pre-populate the below list with the 'unconfirmed' information from there but I think it will be better if it grows organically :-)

Comment: It depends on the hardware (can the voice be sent to the processor) and the baseband (which can always be updated) and the carrier network, and the legality in a particular country around doing this. Any list  here will be very fluid as basebands are constantly updated, custom ROMs can sometimes enable the feature on a device that doesn't officially support this feature. There is an API for this function but my conversations with network providers seem to indicate that most people do not want to be recorded and there are legal ramifications in many places. There's too many variables.

Comment: @RossC Thank you for listing the extra factors, I was wondering what else needs to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

## Android phones ***WITH*** in-line call recording capability

- a
- b
- c

## Android phones ***WITHOUT*** in-line call recording capability

- HTC Incredible S (possible with custom kernel)
- [Motorola Atrix 4G MB860](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Atrix_4G) (UK) (an unofficial ROM enabling the feature known to exist)
- n

## What handset makers say

***Motorola UK*** - "We are sorry to inform you that due to privacy reasons, none of our phones comes with the in-call recording feature. There are some applications in Google Play that may perform this, however we cannot give support for their use. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause you."

***Acer UK*** - "In order to use the in line call recording, the unit should have the call recorder application on the unit. You can download the application from google store."

***Sony UK*** - "Sadly we can confirm that no Sony Xperia handset has the ability to record calls as standard. However you may be able to download a third party application to do this but as it would be third party we would not be able to gaurantee it would fully work. We apologise for any inconvenience caused by this."

***Samsung UK*** - "Unfortunately, we don't have a handset on the market that has this as a registered feature. However, there may be some third party applications available for download that may allow you to record telephone conversations. As these are third party and not developed by Samsung, I am unable to recommend any specific application to you."

***LG UK*** - "I am really sorry to advise that we don’t have a handset that will do in-line call recording I would like to apologize for this."